# jQuery DataTables - Remove search Label

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jquery datatable and I want to remove search text label before input and i have no experience with jquery how to remove search label ? please help me thanks.

[image]

**Jquery datatable**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#userTable").dataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        "defaultContent": "-",
        "targets": "_all"
    }]
  });

//custom format of Search boxes
$('[type=search]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "Search...");
    $(this).before('<span class="fas fa-search icon"></span>');
});
});
```

Comment: Try with `language: { search: "" },`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery DataTables - Remove Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252841/jquery-datatables-remove-label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With this code:

```
$("#dataTable").DataTable({
    language : { search : "" },
});
```